# HDRI stop working when blender restart

Tags: rendering, hdri

HDRI do not work anymore when blender restart.

It is still as an environment texture but all becomes pink like nothing was there.
I have to reload the HDRI each times manually.
The path for the HDRI in in my documents.

I don't understand.
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure ... when reloaded you saved file and closed, right? What do you mean reload ... drag and drop, click on Folder icon, ...? Does in happen also with a new file? When reloaded and you check path to the file does it correct? Do you use some special character somewhere on the path?

Comment: maybe you renamed your folder where your hdri are in? or deleted or renamed your HDRI?

Comment: So it doesn't work when I save a "startup default file" with an HDRI. When I launch a new general (New session) the HDRI is there liked to the node but not displaying. But if I "save" my work normally it works.

Comment: I can't confirm that ... when I add HDRi Environment texture and Save as Startup File, reopening blender has all set OK.

Comment: Do not work for me...